# Algorithm for Shortest Path Tree with runtime O(kn + m)

Tags: algorithm, runtime, shortest-path

Is there an algorithm that can build a shortest-path tree in a directed graph with weights 0, 1, ..., k in a run time of O(kn + m), where n is the number of vertices and m the number of edges?

I thought Dijkstras algorithm might satisfy this but it doesn't depend on the weight of the edges. (I'm confused as to how this could even be the case).

What would such an algorithm look like?

Answer (score 1):

The key is a **topological sort** of the (acyclic) graph, which allows to easily calculate the distance to each vertex. The approach has O(n + m) complexity:

```
1) Initialize dist[] = {INF, INF, …} and dist[s] = 0 where s is the source vertex.
2) Create a Topological order of all vertices. [complexity: O(n+m)]
3) For every vertex u in topological order: [complexity: O(n+m)]
       For every adjacent vertex v:
            If (dist[v] > dist[u] + weight(u, v)):
                dist[v] = dist[u] + weight(u, v)
```

Step 3 also immediately provides the shortest path through the graph.